# Android TabLayout changes tab after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, tabs, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-tablayout

I have an activty with a tabLayout and two tabs. In each tab I have a different fragment with a list of elements(RecyclerView) managed by an RecyclerView adapter. For each element of each list i have a button that removes the element from the list.

The click listener of the button is setted in the adapter. The problem arises when I'm in the second tab and i remove an element from the list. After the notifyDatSetChanged() the current tab moves to the first tab and I don't want that!

This is my code:
This is my declaration and set of the adapter in 2 different fragments:

FRAG 1

```
 adapterList = new NotificationListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.notification_list_element, teamsLeader, null, leadershipTeam); 
 list.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

FRAG 2

```
 adapterList = new NotificationListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.notification_list_element, teamsMember, membershipTeam, null); 
 list.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

And this is the constructor of my adapter:

```
public NotificationListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<DBTeam> notifications, ArrayList<MembershipTeam> membershipTeam, ArrayList<TeamInfo> leadershipTeam) {
    this.notifications = notifications;
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.membershipTeam = membershipTeam;
    this.leadershipTeam = leadershipTeam;
}
```

In my onBindViewHolder i have a switch case for different view types:
Mi imageView removeItem has a clickListener that calls a method.

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            ImageView removeItem;
            LinearLayout getItemDetail;
            switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                case CHECKIN:
                    BaseHolder vh1 = (BaseHolder) holder;
                    configureViewHolder(vh1, position, context.getString(R.string.notification_checkin_title), R.drawable.notification_checkin);
                    removeItem = vh1.getRemoveItemImage();
                    getItemDetail = vh1.getDetail_layout();

                    removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            removeItem(context, notifications, position);
                        }
                    });

                    getItemDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            getMemberItemDetail(context, notifications, position);
                        }
                    });

                    break;
AND SO ON
```

And this is the removeItem method called in the click listener:

```
private void removeItem(Context context, List<DBTeam> notifications, int position){
    MyRepository.getInstance(context).updateNotificationDBTeamSync(notifications.get(position).getNotificationId(), true);
    notifications.remove(position);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: It is nearly impossible to help you out based solely on the information you gave. At the very least show the code for your RecyclerView adapter including the click listener.

Comment: Hi Leo, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after noticing that my:

```
MyRepository.getInstance(context).updateNotificationDBTeamSync(notifications.get(position).getNotificationId(), true);
```

in

```
private void removeItem(Context context, List<DBTeam> notifications, int position){
    MyRepository.getInstance(context).updateNotificationDBTeamSync(notifications.get(position).getNotificationId(), true);
    notifications.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, notifications.size());
}
```

was calling my activity method that fetches data from DB (using realm). Probably for a bad implementation of realm by me. 
On the fetching data success i'm creating the viewPager adapter instance for the tabLayout and setting it. So the problem was that every time it creates new instance of the viewPager adapter e and by default it gets on the first tab.

I solved the problem by checking if an instance of the viewPager adapter exist or no:

```
if(pagerAdapter == null){
                pagerAdapter = new NotificationPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext(), teamsLeader, teamsMember, membershipTeam, leadershipTeam);
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_notification);
                viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener((ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) mContext);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_notification);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                changeTabsFont(0);
            }
```